# PHP does not use MySQL default sockets

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php

I am having a hard time understanding why PHP cannot connect with `localhost` as a host. I can connect by doing:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

And also, through Sequel Pro I can connect with localhost as a host. But with PHP, I get:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

I am sure it's because of the sockets, because If I try to change to 127.0.0.1 it works.

Why doesn't host work?

Comment: It might help if you showed exactly what you are doing, and not just the error message.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is trying to use different socket then the one on which MySQL is listening.

To see on which socket is MySQL listening, run:

```
 mysqld --verbose --help|grep ^socket
```

> `socket       /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

To see what socket PHP tries to use, you can check output of script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, it is variable `mysqli.default_socket`. You can change it in your `php.ini` file (usually in `/etc/php5/apache2/`).